# Execute Windows batch command after HTML Publisher in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In our Jenkins job we have "Publish HTML Reports" plug-in configured as a Post-build action. I want to copy the files generated by this action to another folder using an "Execute Windows batch command". What I found however, is that it is only possible to execute a batch command as a "Post step" which run before the actions. What can I do in this case to execute the batch after publishing the HTML reports?

**NOTE 1**

One (pretty obvious) solution might seem to add another post build action that will trigger a standalone job which only purpose will be executing a batch file. However it seems that once there is already one external job triggered (which is what's happening in my case), it is impossible to trigger an additional one. The options is actually becoming grey.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most exciting and hacky but you can just add another job that execute the batch( on the files location ) which will be triggered by your job.

If you have already a trigger, replace it with new  job and new job will trigger the old trigger.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's definitely an option. Just seemed odd that such a trivial task would require such "hacking".

Comment: Actually I just checked and I am no longer sure even this is an option. I already have one external project being triggered and apparently you can't trigger more than one. The option in the menu is actually getting grayed out. I will add this as a note to my question.

Comment: Updated solution